# A question about hFE and hfe of a transistor

Tags: bjt

I read that hfe is the current amplification factor for small signals. And hFE is the current amplification factor for DC signals.

Does that mean hFE should be used when biasing and hfe should be used for the AC analysis? Or is in practice one of them is used? It seems hfe and hFE are quite close(?). Which one matters more in practice fx. to read in a datasheet?

Comment: In my opinion hfe and hFE are one and the same parameter. But please prove me wrong by showing me a datasheet where hfe and hFE are mentioned separately and do not have the same value.

Comment: I've learned that hFE is for large signal => DC. and hfe for small signal => AC. Though my teacher was... special... so I can certainly have been taught wrong. - Or maybe that nomenclature is not widely used.

Comment: Yes - from the definition, both are different (hFE for DD and hfe for ac). However, for practical purposes it makes no sense to take this difference into consideration because both are equipped with very large tolerances. One is as good as the other one.

Answer (score 2):

\$h_{FE} , h_{fe}\$ have always been valid different specifications, but only companies like Diodes Inc. are diligent in including these parameters.

[image]

Each affects the tolerance of design errors for DC stability and AC gain, so it depends what is more important.

Comment: I've had occasion to work with Diodes Inc regarding the development of a custom diode detector. Very good people to work with (at the time, anyway.) Nice catch regarding a datasheet with both parameters listed!

Comment: It was an easy catch from a company with more than 100 patents  on low Vce(sat)  fabrication which also pioneered low rCE BJT’s and the first to include rCE in the datasheet.

Comment: Well, it would be kind of pointless to pioneer low rCE BJTs and then NOT include the rCE in the spec sheet. I can just imagine the marketing department exploding and hitting the ceiling if the documentation department failed here.

Comment: The example I showed MMBT3904 is not a candidate for low rCE. It is exclusive to their unique designs only and unique p/n’s .   The 3904 is generic.

Comment: I'll take the point. I smell a marketing department making sure that they "lead the way" in some sense they can use to get attention, sales-wise. But that could just be me *projecting*. In any case, I found them to be wonderful and helpful folks. End of that story.

Answer (score 1):

The current gain (\$\beta\$, \$h_{FE}\$, and/or \$h_{fe}\$) varies widely over devices within a single family, let alone across many families. And it's also a function of temperature (and time.) The best one can do is speak in terms of being within a "ballpark" (some factor that expresses the range.)

---

Perhaps to get a feel for the difference between the two ways of looking that the current gain (AC and DC), you might consider the idea of a car. You can set it running at a particular speed on a flat road by supplying the engine with a certain rate of fuel. Different vehicles of the same model, from the same manufacturer, will have different speeds on the same road because there are variations in many complex factors that cannot be well controlled. I'm sure this makes sense to you.

Now, if we change the rate of fuel, all of these same models of car will either increase or decrease their speed on the road. But again, there will be differences. We could now provide curves expressing the "typical efficiency" (as measured by \$\text{Eff}=\frac{\text{speed}}{\text{rate of fuel}}\$), so that others using these vehicles would have an idea of what to expect for different rates of fuel being applied.

This "efficiency" curve might be thought as roughly similar to the idea of a DC current gain curve for a transistor. The typical curve (shown over collector current magnitudes) shows you how "efficient" the transistor typically is, and does so for various levels of DC collector currents (aka "fuel rates" in the car scenario.)

What's remarkable about BJTs (and is probably not at all similar regarding cars as described above) is that this current gain efficiency curve is relatively ***flat*** over a fairly wide range of collector currents. The exact value is ***not known***, since there are substantial variations between devices. (Though you can expect the actual value of a specific device to often be within perhaps a factor of 1.5 or so, either way.) But what you ***can*** rely upon is that whatever the value actually ***is*** for a device, that if you select an operating point correctly that the current gain won't vary too much when the collector current varies by an order of magnitude in either direction. That fact is pretty remarkable and it is used by engineers. Not a specific value, but instead the fact that it stays relatively constant.

---

So far, I've only talked about the DC case. I've adjusted the fuel rate up and down for the car and developed a typical curve that represents all cars of the same model and make. But what about the AC case?

Well, for the car analogy, this would be like making small variations in the fuel rate (without significantly changing the fuel rate setting) and seeing what kinds of slight changes in speed result from that. So if a car was going at 50 mph at a fuel rate of 2 gph, achieving an "efficiency" of 25 mpg, then you might reasonably expect that if you changed the fuel rate to 2.001 gph, the speed would likely reach 50.025 mph. In short, the instantaneous "efficiency" would be close to the average "efficiency" at that particular fuel rate.

This is similar to the case of the BJT's current gain. You might make a tiny variation in the collector current and measure the tiny variation in the base current and compute an instantaneous current gain that is quite similar to the average current gain at that operating point.

It's natural to expect this. It would be unusual to get something that was very much different from that, in fact. (Please do let me know if you discover such a behavior *before you publish* so that I can take credit for this discovery!!) But there also may be some differences due to subtle physical behaviors that are smoothed over when taking averages. So you should expect some difference. But perhaps not a lot.

---

I hope that helps a little in trying to understand the differences (there is a difference of sorts, but it is usually not something anyone dwells on.)

The take-away here is that:

- Average BJT current gain is remarkably flat over a wide range of collector currents. This allows for some planning regarding a circuit design.
- BJT current gain can vary by a factor 1.5 or more between parts within a family even at the same temperature.
- BJT current gain varies widely over temperature.
- Differences between the meaning of DC (average) current gain and AC (instantaneous) current gain are usually washed out by part and temperature variations.

So when working with a circuit, you need to have some idea about the operating temperature range you expect because that, added to the part variation expectations, will tell you more about how widely to expect variation of the current gain. That will then tell you something about the current compliances needed by your driving circuit.

But you can at least depend to some degree on the fact that the current gain is relatively flat and that *distortion* due only to variation of current gain should be minimal.

---

Side note. There are combinations of BJTs that can be applied to increase the current gain: Darlington and Sziklai, for example.

Comment: Regarding increase of current gain: Some newbies think that a higher current gain would be good for a higher voltage gain. But this is not the case. The only advantage of a Darlington pair is an increase in the input resistance - thats all! Two gain stages with the same DC quiescent current (same DC operating point) will have the same voltage gain - even for a large difference in the current gain.

Comment: @LvW Yeah. Actually I agree with you and it's not at all important what I wrote there at the end. It might even be confusing. I will just remove that last bit. Thanks.